# Python: writing to file within loop reading that file?

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop, file-io

I'm wondering if, in python (windows), I can write to a file pointer in the same loop structure that I'm doing a read from that same file.

If I wish to do an append to the filestream and continue to read-process (including the written data), would the following work?:

```
f = open('myfile.xyz', "a+b")
f.seek(0, 0)
for l in f:
  l = "{}\n".format(l.rstrip()) # convert windows lines to posix, removing other terminal whitespace
  specific_condition = do_stuff(l) # returns True/False
  if specific_condition:
    p = f.tell()
    f.seek(0,os.SEEK_END)
    f.write(multiline_string)
    f.seek(p,os.SEEK_SET)
f.close()
```

I've previously had issues with python balking whenever I change an object that I'm iterating over (e.g. by deleting an item in a `dict` that I'm iterating over), but since I'm not changing the file pointer itself in this case, are there any issues? Does the answer differ if the line that I read WAS the last line in the file?

I'm specifically curious about python 2.7, but if the py3+ answer differs, I'm sure I'll eventually appreciate that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question re: py2.7, the following works, albeit convoluted. Note, I could not use `for line in f` syntax, due to read-ahead "optimization" in python.

```
import base64, os

csvstring = "this,is,a,csv,string\r\nthis,is,another,such,string"
b64string = base64.b64encode(csvstring).decode('utf-8')

f = open('myfile.xyz', "w+b")
f.write(b64string+os.linesep)
f.write(b64string) # no final \n to test case where file doesn't end in \n
f.close()

fmode = "a+b"
f = open('myfile.xyz', fmode)
f.seek(0,os.SEEK_END)
eofpos = f.tell() # aka writepos
try:
  if not eofpos: raise EOFError
  f.seek(eofpos-1, os.SEEK_SET)
  lastchar = f.read(1).replace("\r","\n") # if not \n (or \r), we'll have to append the eol before writing anything else
except (EOFError,IOError,OSError):
  eofpos = 0
  lastchar="\n" # we don't have to add
  eol = os.linesep if fmode.endswith("b") else "\n"
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
firstline = True
linecount = 0
readpos = 0
while 1:
  line = f.readline()
  if not line: break # while (line = f.readline()): # empty string is False
#for line in f:
  """
  can't use `for line in f`, due to read-ahead of file object
  (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next)
  When a file is used as an iterator, typically in a for loop (for example, for line in f: print line),
  the next() method is called repeatedly. This method returns the next input line, or raises StopIteration when EOF is hit.
  In order to make a for loop the most efficient way of looping over the lines of a file (a very common operation),
  the next() method uses a hidden read-ahead buffer. As a consequence of using a read-ahead buffer, combining next()
  with other file methods (like readline()) does not work right. However, using seek() to reposition the file to an absolute
  position will flush the read-ahead buffer.
  """
  linecount += 1
  l = line.rstrip("\n\r") # get rid of terminal end-of-line characters, regardless of the order
  print("{}: {} ({})".format(linecount, l, line.replace("\r","\\r").replace("\n","\\n")))
  if firstline:
    if fmode.endswith("b"):
      if len(l) != len(line):
        eol = line[len(l):] # grab the end of line used elsewhere in this file, so as to not throw off the file reader later
      else:
        eol = os.linesep
    else: # text files, don't use linesep, use \n
      eol = "\n"
    firstline = False
  if (len(l)):
    if l.count(',') < 2:
      print("\tLine {} with insufficient delimiters (,) encountered. Trying to see if it's encoded. length {} line: {}".format(linecount,len(l),l))
      try:
        prepend = '' if (lastchar == '\n') else eol
        testme = prepend + base64.b64decode(l).decode('utf-8', errors='ignore') + eol
        if testme.count(',') >= 1: # here we'll just require 2+ items
          readpos = f.tell()
          f.seek(eofpos,os.SEEK_SET) # otherwise after a read, the filepointer is set back to the original eol before write
          f.write(testme)
          eofpos += len(testme)
          f.flush() # otherwise the write may be thrown out with subsequent re-writes
          f.seek(readpos,os.SEEK_SET)
          lastchar = '\n' # the end of file should now either be \r or \r\n after the next write
      except (TypeError,UnicodeError): # e.g. padding error
        print("\t\tWARNING: line not able to be unencoded")
      except (EOFError,IOError,OSError):
        print("\t\tERROR: writing unencoded data back to file")
    else: # 3 or more items, 2 or more commas
      datstrm = l.split(",")
      print("\t{} item line {} OK: {}".format(len(datstrm),linecount,l))
  else:
    print("\tBlank line encountered at line {}".format(linecount))
f.close()
```

output:

```
1: dGhpcyxpcyxhLGNzdixzdHJpbmcNCnRoaXMsaXMsYW5vdGhlcixzdWNoLHN0cmluZw== (dGhpcyxpcyxhLGNzdixzdHJpbmcNCnRoaXMsaXMsYW5vdGhlcixzdWNoLHN0cmluZw==\r\n)
        Line 1 with insufficient delimiters (,) encountered. Trying to see if it's encoded. length 68 line: dGhpcyxpcyxhLGNzdixzdHJpbmcNCnRoaXMsaXMsYWdWNoLHN0cmluZw==
2: dGhpcyxpcyxhLGNzdixzdHJpbmcNCnRoaXMsaXMsYW5vdGhlcixzdWNoLHN0cmluZw== (dGhpcyxpcyxhLGNzdixzdHJpbmcNCnRoaXMsaXMsYW5vdGhlcixzdWNoLHN0cmluZw==\r\n)
        Line 2 with insufficient delimiters (,) encountered. Trying to see if it's encoded. length 68 line: dGhpcyxpcyxhLGNzdixzdHJpbmcNCnRoaXMsaXMsYWdWNoLHN0cmluZw==
3: this,is,a,csv,string (this,is,a,csv,string\r\n)
        5 item line 3 OK: this,is,a,csv,string
4: this,is,another,such,string (this,is,another,such,string\r\n)
        5 item line 4 OK: this,is,another,such,string
5: this,is,a,csv,string (this,is,a,csv,string\r\n)
        5 item line 5 OK: this,is,a,csv,string
6: this,is,another,such,string (this,is,another,such,string\r\n)
        5 item line 6 OK: this,is,another,such,string
```